# Acumatica PXParent behaviour with table with Cascade delete

Tags: acumatica

PXParent Attribute
Creates a reference to the parent record, establishing a parent-child relationship between two tables.

Does anyone know if PXParent is used and the underlying tables have a Cascade delete set if this causes any issues?
I would rather the database has referential integrity than rely on the framework application code to maintain this.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the goals for using the PXParentAttribute (that it will cascade delete the children and even if the child is a parent to more children it will delete those children too). I would use PXParent vs any configurations in SQL Server or MySql to accomplish the same goal.

If you want to setup a parent child relationship using PXParent and leave the children during a delete you would set the attribute LeaveChildren property to true (it is false by default).

Example:

```
[PXParent(typeof(Select<Schedule, 
    Where<Schedule.scheduleID, Equal<Current<WZScenario.scheduleID>>>>),
    LeaveChildren = true)]
```

Adding to referential integrity you can also assign (on the dac fields) foreign references in case such references are attempted to be deleted. Inventory Warehouses for example. If you have a DAC that uses SiteID (warehouse) and want to make sure when someone tries to delete the warehouse (if referenced in a row of your DAC/table) it would prevent the deletion. You can use the `PXForeignReferenceAttribute` to do this. Here is an example on the IN Transaction dac (INTran):

```
[IN.SiteAvail(typeof(INTran.inventoryID), typeof(INTran.subItemID))]
[PXDefault(typeof(INRegister.siteID))]
[PX.Data.ReferentialIntegrity.Attributes.PXForeignReference(typeof(Field<siteID>.IsRelatedTo<INSite.siteID>))]
public virtual Int32? SiteID
{
    get
    {
        return this._SiteID;
    }
    set
    {
        this._SiteID = value;
    }
}
```

If you have custom tables, the same logic would apply if you point to your custom DACS/Fields using PXParent and/or PXForeignReference.

Either way the framework should cover you needs and would be my preference.

Comment: Hi Brendan. Thanks for responding, must of what you have said I know. What I don't like is the application being responsible for referential integrity of the database. If I wanted to build another application or UI interface to connect I dont want to have to build in the code to do this. Also I suspect the database is far better and quicker at deleting the child records.

Comment: Because of the Acumatica caching you might run into issues if you let the database do it. And general rule is to avoid direct connections to the database. For ISVs and those distributing customization database access is not an option. If you want to do this on your own database for a single instance customization i suppose it would work but  I would still not recommend it.The caching and framework provides a lot of tools and it is best to use them vs external configurations in the database or outside database connections. Just my thoughts.

Comment: @Brendan Does this also work for DAC extensions?  I added a Customer selector to an existing screen and no warnings are given upon deleting, nor is the record deleted.